# Convert latin1 to UTF8

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB - with the table articles.

I want to convert the title, and content field to utf8
now - all data looks like this: `×¤×•×¨×˜×œ ×¨×¢×œ × ×¤×ª×— ×¨×©×ž×™×ª!`
I want it to become normal hebrew characters.

Thanks

Comment: do with `phpmyadmin`, go to that table, alter the attribute...simple

Comment: Tried it already, the data on pma its self looks same.

Comment: It's difficult to say what to do without more information, but one thing to be aware of is that changing a table's character encoding in MySQL does *not* convert the data to the new encoding.  The actual bytes stored in the database remain the same.

Comment: Rob is right... first change and then insert new data and see the result

Comment: Even it does work when inserting new data - I need to convert the old data..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make mysqldump from this database. Then download something like Notepad++, open dump file, convert it to UTF8, then replace through the file all encodings to utf-8 including the first SET NAMES operator.

If you make dump to file via phpMyAdmin (with default settings) use output file encoding ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 as you can see by default.

Answer (score 9):

The following MySQL function will return the correct utf8 string after double-encoding:

```
CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

It can be used with an UPDATE statement to correct the fields:

```
UPDATE tablename SET field = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```

Comment: this truncates the word on the special character :(

Answer (score 8):

if you need to convert the whole database , you can back it as `databaseback.sql` file then form your command line 
`iconv -f latain -t utf-8  < databaseback.sql > databaseback.utf8.sql`

you can use the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php
to convert each row in php in case you don't have command line access

and lastly don't forget to convert the collation  of each field in phpmyadmin , then you can resotre the utf8 back easily

**update**

if you got `iconv is not recognized` , it means that you don't have `iconv` installed

**much more easier solution is :** 
Migrating MySQL Data to Unicode

http://daveyshafik.com/archives/166-migrating-mysql-data-to-unicode.html

Comment: I've tried it on CMD - got : 'iconv' is not recognized as an in operable program or batch file.

Comment: iconv: conversion from `latain' is not supported

Answer (score 4):

You can write a little php script which does the conversion. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php This is how I did this.

And remember to use strict mode! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#102510

In pseudocode it would be sth. like this:

```
str = getDataAsString()
if(!isUTF8(str)) {
  str = convert2UTF8(str)
}
saveStr2DB()
```

Comment: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#102510 - You have to set the last parameter to "true", then it will find out the correct encoding :)

Comment: what should i put in the middle arg?

Comment: use this: mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true);

Comment: I get UTF-8 , what should i do with it? if its utf-8, then how do i convert it?

Comment: if the database is set to utf8, so what´s about the output html page, do you view this with phpmyadmin or within your own script? check if your browser and the webpage is set to utf-8 as well

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field_name` `field_name` VARCHAR( 200 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```