# Update special characters from column in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It's been a while since we migrated from MySql to SQL Server 2017.

We have a table that contains email html content, the problem we are facing is the characters like `'` are stored into SQL DB like this  `â€˜`, I tried to change the collation to rectify this but it did not worked.

Current collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I have tried many things like update the table column collation/charset to utf8, but nothing seems to work. I don't know how many special characters in my column table which contains lots of email templates.

[Strange Characters in database text: Ã, Ã, ¢, â‚ €,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861358/strange-characters-in-database-text-%C3%83-%C3%83-%C2%A2-%C3%A2-%E2%82%AC)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/84241/strange-query-result-from-sql-server

[Convert text value in SQL Server from UTF8 to ISO 8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1)

So far I have found these special characters `â€˜, â€™, â€”, â€œ ,â€, Â`. As per my understanding there can be few solutions:

1. Find each special characters manually and update each special character with SQL statement.
2. There can be a regex to pull all the special characters and replace them with correct ones, but that to pulls all other html characters.
3. If possible update the collation/charset of table column, that may possibly fix these characters but updating the collation/charset does not fix the issue in my case.

UPDATE 1:
The data type to column is nvarchar(-1)

I am open to any solutions that can solve my problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the data type of the problem column to your question.

Comment: What is the replacement value(s) ?

Comment: Is this data still continuing to appear in your database, or is this all historical? if the former, this would suggest that there's an encoding problem in your application too; I'd *guess* somewhere it's being implicitly converted from UTF-8 to code page 1252 (`â€˜` saved in ANSI 1252 and then opened in UTF-8 results in `‘`).

Comment: Also, in regards to changing the table to UTF-8; you can't (not in 2017). UTF-8 collations weren't added until SQL Server 2019. If you need non ANSI characters (or characters outside of the codepage), then you'll need to use an `nvarchar` which uses UCS-2 or UTF-16 depending on if the collation has Supplementary Characters.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have updated the question and added the column data type which is `nvarchar`.

Comment: Aside... UTF-8 is an encoding for the entire range of Unicode code points. There's no UTF-8 to iso-8859-1 conversion that isn't "lossy," i.e.: you'll lose any code points that don't exist in iso-8859-1.

Comment: @Larnu The data in table already exist(historical) which causes issue and when entering new data works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We recently did the same thing a few years ago, migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2017, and we left the collation as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. We've found we don't get special/error characters if we pass strings with ASCII/Unicode characters.

I don't remember if UTF-8 also works, but you essentially need to make sure your data inputs are good otherwise you're going to get those characters. We have to double-check our information coming from an international supplier.

You can find more information about Collation here: [SQL Server 2017 Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017)